# Cant browse Android phone with KDE on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, files, kde, android

I'm using Kubuntu and my Android phone (Samsung s7) is connected to it with KDE connect. I can send files from the phone to the PC but it keeps on failing.

It successfully rings my phone and shows the charge percentage, but when I try to browse the device it says

```
Failed to mount filesystem: device not responding
```

Comment: Have you made sure the device is unlocked when attempting to browse it? My phone won't let me browse the files if the screen has locked.